# serialize Id's and PHP for each

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, foreach

Hello i need some jQuery help by giving serial ids to input text like `qty0` , `rate1` , `amt2`  i++ so on document load or by giving addnew row button

This is my html code

```
<tr class="item-row1">
   <td><input id="qty1" name="qty1" type="text"></td>
   <td>
      <select id="selectitem1">
         <option value="">Select One...</option>    
         <option value="17">Apple</option>
         <option value="18">Orange</option>
         <option value="9">Banana</option>     
      </select>
   </td>
   <td><input id="desc1" name="desc1" type="text"></td>
   <td><input id="rate1" name="rate1" type="text"></td>
   <td><input id="amt1"  name="amt1"  type="text"></td>
</tr>

<tr class="item-row2">
   <td><input id="qty2" name="qty2" type="text"></td>
   <td>
       <select id="selectitem">
          <option value="">Select One...</option>    
          <option value="17">Apple</option>
          <option value="18">Orange</option>
          <option value="9">Banana</option>     
       </select>
   </td>
   <td><input id="desc2" name="desc2" type="text"></td>
   <td><input id="rate2" name="rate2" type="text"></td>
   <td><input id="amt2"  name="amt2" type="text"></td>
</tr>
```

and so on..!

Please help me with creating a php code right now i am using this code

```
$id1 = $_POST['id1'];
$qty1 = $_POST['qty1'];
$qty2 = $_POST['qty2'];
$rate1 = $_POST['rate1'];
$rate2 = $_POST['rate2'];
sql_query =" INSERT INTO products (id,qty,rate,amt) WHERE id = $id VALUES ($id,$qty,$rate,$amt);
```

I want to create a loop code and i don't know how will i get all possible values from page and post into MySQL `WHERE id = $id + number`

Comment: Could you please rephrase your post? I do not understand what you are asking. Also, your INSERT statement seems to be invalid. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert.html

Answer (score 1):

for each of the incrementing names, like desc1, desc2, rate1, rate2, etc, you can write them as desc[], selectItem[], etc.  This array snytax will show up in PHP as $_POST['selectItem'] and it will be an array.  Then you can just loop over one of these and make all the INSERTS, i.e.

```
 for($i = 0, $l = count($_POST['selectItem']); $i < $l; $i++)){
   sql_query ="INSERT INTO products (id,qty,rate,amt) WHERE id = $id VALUES ('" . $_POST['selectItem'][$i] . "','" . $_POST['qty'][$i] . "', '" . $_POST['rate'][$i] . "', '" . $_POST['amt'][$i] . "')";
    //execute query
 }
```

Comment: 1) ESCAPE USER INPUT IN YOUR SQL!! 2) You can't put multidimensional or associative arrays directly into strings. You have to do `"... VALUES ({$_POST['selectItem'][$i]}, {$_POST['qty'][$i]}, ..."`, with variables surrounded by `{}`

Comment: right, good call on the escaping, I suppose you can never assume that someone will know to already do that.

Comment: This is i am asking for.

http://css-tricks.com/examples/EditableInvoice/

I am trying to make a invoice system like showed in above link and when user will click on save button i am asking help that how we will get all textbox values and insert into MySQL

Comment: I get that.  You were still using POST and all your form values, so it didn't seem like you were using AJAX/jQuery with the option to serialize the form.  Decided on which implementation you would really want and then we can provide you more specific help.

Comment: it doesn't matter to me either you help me with php or jquery my main point is to submit each prodcut detail with quantity and amount where row is variable

I can do php code manual like first i define to 
    INSERT INTO product values $qty1 then 
    INSERT INTO product values $qty2 and so on..!
but i just need a loop method.